# Retrieving full request string using Ruby curl

Tags: ruby, curb

I intend to send a request like the following:

```
c = Curl::Easy.http_post("https://example.com", json_string   
    ) do |curl|
      curl.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
      curl.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      curl.headers['Api-Version'] = '2.2'
    end
```

I want to log the exact http request that is being made.  Is there a way to get the actual request that was made (base path, query parameters, headers and body)?

Comment: Have you tried setting `curl.verbose = true` within your block?

Answer (score 1):

The [on_debug handler](http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html#M000102) has helped me before. In your example you could try:

```
curl.on_debug do |type, data|
  puts type, data
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the solution in differents manner:

Inside your block you can put:

```
curl.verbose = true   # that prints a detailed output of the connection
```

Or outside the block:

```
c.url  # return the url with queries
c.total_time # retrieve the total time for the prev transfer (name resolving, TCP,...)
c.header_str # return the response header
c.headers # return your call header
c.body_str # return the body of the response
```

Remember to call c.perform (if not yet performed) before call these methods.

Many more option can be found here: http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html#M000001